# ngrx router-store - testing router navigation effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-unit-test

I have effects and tests working as follow:

**LoginRedirect Effect**

```
  @Effect()
  public loginSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoginSuccess>(AuthActionTypes.LoginSuccess),
    map( action => action.payload ),
    concatMap( (payload: Client) => [
      new SecondAction(payload),
    ]),
    tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/somepage']))
  );
```

**LoginRedirect Effect Test**

```
  describe('#loginSuccess$', () => {
    it('should trigger SecondAction action and redirect to somepage', () => {
      spyOn(effects['router'], 'navigate');

      actions = hot('-a-', { a: new LoginSuccess({} as any)});
      expected = cold('-b', { b: new SecondAction({} as any)});

      expect(effects.loginSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
      expect(effects['router'].navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Tests are passing as expected. I am trying to write the same tests for an Observable of an action that happens on the ngrx router-store. Example, here is my Effect.

**clearError Effect**

```
  @Effect()
  public clearError$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION), // <-- not using the conventional 
    mapTo(new ClearErrorMessage())
  );
```

**clearError EffectTest**

```
  describe('#clearError$', () => {
    it('should trigger ClearErrorMessage action', () => {
      spyOn(effects['actions$'], 'pipe').and.returnValue(hot('-a', { a: ROUTER_NAVIGATION }));

      expected = cold('-b', { b: new ClearErrorMessage() });

      expect(effects.clearError$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  });
```

However, here I am getting an error:

```
Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 10, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: ClearErrorMessage({ type: '[Auth] ClearErrorMessage' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: what is "ClearErrorMessage()"???

Comment: @ALGDB, it's an internal action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also use `actions` just like you did in your first example instead of `spyOn(...)`

Also `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` is just a string, you'll have to create an action.

```
describe('#clearError$', () => {
   actions$ = hot('-a---', { a: {type: ROUTER_NAVIGATION} });   
   expected = cold('-b', { b: new ClearErrorMessage() });
   expect(effects.clearError$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```